# Underscore "defaults" from scratch

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I've been trying to rewrite the _.defaults method from underscore.js and I keep getting this error:

> should copy source properties to undefined properties in the destination object‣
> AssertionError: expected { a: 'existing' } to deeply equal { a: 'existing', b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }

Here's the missing conditions:

> -should copy source properties to undefined properties in the destination object and should return the destination object

and my code:

```
_.defaults = function (destination, source) {
  Object.keys(destination).forEach(key => {
    if (destination[key] === undefined || destination[key] === null) {
      destination[key] = source[key];
    }
  })
  return destination;

};
```

Comment: Why not use `Object.assign()`?

Comment: I keep seeing people asking questions about rewriting Underscore functions. Is there a tutorial website somewhere that suggests this as exercises? I maintain Underscore so it makes me curious.

Answer (score 0):

The idea in [`_.defaults`](https://underscorejs.org/#defaults) is that keys from the source object might be missing entirely in the destination object. So you need to iterate the keys of the source object instead of those of the destination object:

```js
_.defaults = function (destination, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    if (destination[key] === undefined || destination[key] === null) {
      destination[key] = source[key];
    }
  })
  return destination;

};
```

Side note: you can write `x == null` instead of `x === null || x === undefined`. Saves some precious keystrokes.

```js
_.defaults = function (destination, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    if (destination[key] == null) {
      destination[key] = source[key];
    }
  })
  return destination;

};
```